# Linux TCP: packet segmentation?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I am working on a virtualization environment (Linux over HyperV). The Linux driver for the virtual NIC supports TSO and GSO (tcp segmentation is ON and generic segmentation is ON).

Now, I create TCP socket and the send buffer set to 128K.
But based on ifconfig data (TX bytes and TX packets), the average packet size is about 11 K.

So my question is, where is my packet be segmented (from 128K to 11K)? How do I control/configure this in socket options or TCP options?

thanks!

===========EDIT==================

I have an application which can reach 8Gbps throughput in a 10G network with 32 TCP connections - in this case, the average packet size is about 20 Kbytes which is pretty good; but when I increased the TCP connections to 256, then the throughput is just about 1Gbps as the packet size on NIC is down to about 3 KBytes.

I know the packet size is critical to the performance as the cost of processing traffic is per packet, not per bytes, so the packet on NIC, it is better if bigger.

SO, MY QUESTION IS: how do I increase the TCP packet size? Is there any TCP settings control this?

Comment: In short, not at all. The size of segments is the size of the NIC's MTU minus a few bytes. Segmentation is a normal thing and falls under "not your business". TCP is (conceptionally) a _stream_. It neither knows messages nor datagrams or anything the like. You write to and read from the stream irrespective of what happens on the "wire", agnostic of such things. Besides, those 11kB advertized by your virtual NIC are a mighty big MTU already, larger than the maximum jumbogram size on ethernet.

Comment: Thanks. My application can reach 8Gbps in a 10G network with 32 TCP connections - in this case, the average packet size is about 20Kbytes which is pretty good; but when I increased the TCP connections to 256, then the throughput is just about 1Gbps as the packet size on NIC is about 3KBytes. I know the packet size is critical to the performance as the cost of processing traffic is per packet, not per bytes, so the packet on NIC, it is better if bigger. SO, MY QUESTION IS: how do I increase the TCP packet size? Is there any TCP settings control this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a little bit confusing, but there are a number of settings that you need to play with to get 10GigE to work right on Linux.

See here:
http://dak1n1.com/blog/7-performance-tuning-intel-10gbe/

Answer (score 0):

- Setting the socket option SO_SNDBUF, SO_RCVBUF might help, but the TCP IP does not guarantees the chunks size when received / sent.